# Can't Close A Popup in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

I did something in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 and now there is a partial popup in the upper right hand corner. Clicking it or right clicking it doesn't seem to do anything. If I click the links Connect or Get Started for free goes to my Microsoft account. I Can't figure out how to close this popup because it is only the lower part showing: I can't drag it to see the upper part of the pop up. Because I can't close it it pretty much makes Visual Studio useless.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.

By picking the bottom of the popup and dragging it I got the popup to expand. Then I could close it. This is pretty bad design by Microsoft.